# How can I connect an object with particle instances on an emitter via some Curve/Geometry connection

Tags: animation, particles, constraints, animation-nodes

[image]

Hi im trying to get a dynamic electricity effect going on:

Basically, I want an object to pass over a particle emitter, and have lines show up connecting itself to all the moving particle instances on the emitter plane.

No idea how to do this.. seems i'd need to recreate each particle and animate it, then add "connection" curve/meshes for each particle, and then clamp them on both the passing object and each particle. THis seems super tedious if I want 50+ particles.

Any idea how to approach this? I have a hunch 'animation nodes' might help"?
Thanks.

Comment: Related https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9MvcCXsHHY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quJpVzKK8gc or [any other](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=animation+nodes+particle+link)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks!, I'll check those out. I'm also condiering just doing a particle system for each particle and having a vortex effect on the object so it 'sucks' the particles coming off each big particle creating a 'connection' looking effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an edges between each alive particle and the object using the *Create Edges Node* then use the *Splines From Edges Node* to generate splines from that and output it.

[image: Node Tree]